# qt problems for playing audio beside fmod system

Tags: c++, c, qt, embedded-linux, fmod

I try to run 2 server at the same time on ubuntu, in order to support two groups of softwares.

One of them is a *qt server* that uses *QSound* objects and the other is written in C and uses *fmod* to play audio.

When I run the *fmod* based server and then run the other, I receive `"Error opening audio device"`.

What should I do to have both running fine simultaneously?

Comment: It's been ages since I've used QSound, but from memory you need to have NAS controlling the audio device.  But you should just forget it b/c it's a nightmare.  Phonon is generally the way to go for multimedia in Qt 4.X.  I've not messed with sounds since upgrading to 5.x but apparently the Qt Multimedia module is the way to go now.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-index.html

Comment: [Salaam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salaam) Zahra! We would need more information about your problem. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34268369/edit) your question and add minimal relevant codes of your servers.